# Does learned features of a neural network have the problem of "reverse causality"?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, causality, reverse-causality

For linear models, when the dependent variable `y` causes the variance of the independent variable `x`, we know that the `reverse causality` problem presents, leading to a biased model.

In the case of neural networks, as high-level features/representations are learned from labels (thus the dependent variable), can I say that every NN model suffers the `reverse causality` problem? I feel subtle about the question and cannot figure it out.